# webpack module federation configuration is returning error: TypeError: fn is not a function while loading

Tags: webpack, nrwl-nx, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

My microfrontend react application is created using Nx Tool.

Below was my webpack  config & when starting the app, I'm getting error that

TypeError: fn is not a function

while loading "./Module" from 8640

```
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;
const nrwlConfig = require('@nrwl/react/plugins/webpack.js');

module.exports = (config, context) => {
  nrwlConfig(config);
  return {
    ...config,

    plugins: [
      ...config.plugins,
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: 'cart',
        filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
        exposes: {
          './Module': './src/remote-entry.ts',
        },
      }),
    ],
  };
};
```

**Things I had tried:**

There is a description in the [webpack doc](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#uncaught-typeerror-fn-is-not-a-function), but I wasnt able to understand what needs to be done.

**Steps to replicate:**

1. Code exists here: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-azwv9t](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-na8unq) or get from GIT:https://github.com/kalingaCoder/React_nx_2
2. Do npm install
3. Do npm run start
4. Open http://localhost:4200/cart with dev console open

Files to check:

apps\cart\webpack.config.js